# Do `const T` and `T` have no difference when taking its nested type?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

```
#include <string>

template<typename T, typename C, typename CR>
void f()
{
    typename T::size_type*     p1{}; // ok
    typename CR::size_type*    p2{}; // error
    typename C::size_type*     p3{}; // Does the C++ standard allow this?        
}

int main()
{
    f<std::string, const std::string, const std::string&>();
}
```

**Do** `const T` **and** `T` **have no difference when taking its nested type?**

Comment: why would you expect the code to be an error even if there was a difference between the two? or what do you mean with "Does the C++ standard allow this?" ?

Comment: @idclev463035818, for example, because `std::string&` will fail here.

Comment: @Evg sorry, I dont get it. there is no `std::string&` in the code

Comment: What difference between `const` and non-`const` are you talking about?

Comment: Yes the standard allows this.  Yes they have no difference when taking its nested type.  The types are identical.

Comment: @idclev463035818, `T::size_type` is valid for `T = std::string` and `T = const std::string`, but is invalid for `T = std::string&`.

Comment: @Evg  got it. Misread the question as being about the difference between `::size_type` and `::size_type` when it is about `CT` vs `T`

Comment: If you need to remove the reference if it has one on the type in your use-case scenario, `<type_traits>` has: `typename std::remove_reference_t<CT>::size_type* p2{};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Indeed, the "nested types" are the same.

A type qualified with `const` and/or `volatile` is a "version" of the unqualified type ([[basic.type.qualifier]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.type.qualifier) in the standard, 6.3.8, paragraph 1) - even if it's not quite the same. This is unlike a pointer or a reference, which, when introduced, form a wholly different type than the type they point or refer to (clauses [[dcl.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ptr) and [[dcl.ptr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref) of the standard, 9.3.3.1 and 9.3.3.2, paragraph 1 in both).

It is also worth mentioning that class-scope types do not get `const`-qualified because you get them from the `const` version of the type - e.g. `std::vector<int>::iterator` is the exact same type as `std::add_const_t<std::vector<int>>::iterator` - but *not* the same type as `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`.

Comment: "The cv-qualified or cv-unqualified versions of a type are distinct types"... What does "distinct" in "distinct types" mean? How distinction between `T` and `const T` is different from distinction between `T` and `T&`?

Comment: @Evg: How about "distinct" in [this sense](https://godbolt.org/z/dJeXTz)?

Comment: @Evg: Ok, I get it. Rephrased, I hope this is better.